# The variables i'm seeing in MySQL workbench does not match up with what i see in my docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, mysql-workbench, my.cnf

Im using docker-compose to setup a mysql instance with a customized configuration file.

Here's what I have in the file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    build: ./db
    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - $HOME/infrastructure/config/:/etc/mysql/conf.d
volumes: 
  mysql_data:
```

When i build the container and connect to my database through mysql workbench, i'm not seeing the correct variables that matching up with what i see in docker. I connected to Bash in my mysql container and executed: 'mysqld --verbose --help' and I see that the variables match up with my configuration file, but not with my mysql workbench.

I'm using MySQL 8.0.

Edit: After running 'mysqladmin variables' in the bash, i realized the variables do **not** match with my my.cnf file.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain me what variables don't match, what commands are you issuing and the docker image/version you are using as base? The config is merged taking the last precedence as docs sugests.

Comment: @filipe Docker version: 18.06.2 , commands: docker-compose up -d --build to build the container | docker exec container_name -it bash to login to the bash | mysqladmin variables for the variables" , and the variable that does not match would be: 'sql_mode'. I am trying to change the sql_mode = ' '

Comment: whats the name of the config override file? File names must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored. Also the setting you want to change must inside  [mysqld] group.

Comment: You say they "don't match". How so? What are they?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I set sql_mode to " " but when i look up the variables after in mysql, it's still set to it's default value"

Comment: @filipe i have the file named "my.cnf" in $HOME/infrastructure/config. Also, when i looked up the order of which default options are being looked up, i'm seeing this: "/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf". My my.cnf is being mounted on /etc/mysql/conf.d.

Comment: You should show us (verbatim) all pieces of evidence. Are you sure you're connecting to the right database?

Comment: Did you see my answer about the setting ? Is not sql_mode but sql-mode.

Comment: @filipe yes, i've tried both and it still did not work.

Comment: @filipe I realized that there were some mysql options i had set in the config file that were depricated. I commented those out and the file successfully mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine and I guess this will answer your question:

- The file must have the ".cnf" extension, otherwise it will be
  ignored.
- In mysql 8.0 the sql mode syntax changed:

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode="modes"
```

You can also use the --sql-mode="" directly in the docker command.